# iOS: GPPSignInButton always asks for "Have offline access" Permission

Tags: ios, google-signin, google-oauth

I've set up the GPPSignInButton based on the following:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app

```
    let googleSignIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    googleSignIn.clientID = GoogleClientID
    googleSignIn.attemptSSO = true
    googleSignIn.homeServerClientID = GoogleServerClientID
    googleSignIn.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"]
    googleSignIn.delegate = self
    googleSignInButton.colorScheme = kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeLight
    googleSignInButton.style = kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide
```

When the user signs in the first time it asks for the correct permissions and returns the `idToken` which gets forwarded to the server and exchanged for an access_token/refresh_token.

However after calling `GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`, signing in again will always ask for the "Have offline access" permission.

I've read through some of the other SO posts referencing this and most of them reference URL parameters "approval_prompt" and "access_type". Given that I'm using the iOS SDK, I don't have the ability to set these parameters.

The url that the app routes to in the web view is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?gpsdk=1.7.1&audience=<server-client-id>&response_type=code&verifier=94014002&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.profile.emails.read&gpbtn=1.1&hl=en&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&client_id=<client-id>&state=702574
```

I have the same scopes ("login" and "email") on the server side, I can't figure out what else I need to do so it doesn't always ask for permission to have offline access.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you are using Google's iOS SDK.

What you are talking is the default behaviour of Google API.

Using below solution you can add "approval_prompt=force" and "access_type=offline" parameters to the URL.

**Solution:**

So as **to add these parameters, you will have to modify GTMOAuth2SignIn.m** and replace the "paramsDict" with following NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"code", @"response_type",
                                 clientID, @"client_id",
                                 scope, @"scope",
                                 @"force", @"approval_prompt",
                                 @"offline", @"access_type",
                                 nil];
```

I am sure after this your issue will be resolved.

**Update:**

For GPPSignin class usage you should check whether trySilentAuthentication is possible.
this api checks if the Signin is possible without user interaction.

**Explanation about trySilentAuthentication**

When you call authenticate, sdk saves a long lived token in the keychain for the user, as well as a short lived token for making API calls. Calling trySilentAuthentication checks whether the long lived token is in the key chain, and generates a new short lived token. If it succeeds it means the user has signed in to that app on that device before, so you generally will want to respond to that appropriately. If it fails (there is no token) it will just return false, or if it can't generate a short lived token it will call finishedWithAuth:error with the error set.

Comment: I installed the SDK via cocoa pods and only have access to the headers. Is there another place to grab the library so I can edit this?

Comment: never mind, I found it on google.code. Thanks for the tip I'll see if it works

Comment: I looked into this, I'm not sure how I can do this while still using the GPPSignIn class, which provides SSO so it will open in a valid google app instead of a web view. Thoughts?

Comment: The issue I'm having is when the user signs out. Which as the documentation states: "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in#a94cc83486f00e4bfa73a21bf82be0f4a" will remove the token from the keychain. I'm using "trySilentAuthentication" when the app starts and it works properly if the user hasn't signed out.