# GIDSignIn set approval_prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin, gidsignin

The problem is that Google asking for offline access only after user has logged out of app and logs in back.

Reading [this](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/12/are-you-using-approvalpromptforce.html) and some other articles I found out that 'approval_prompt' parameter should be set to 'auto', however I can't find how to set it for GIDSignIn. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can't figure out how to change that parameter. 

I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594030/ios-gppsigninbutton-always-asks-for-have-offline-access-permission) which says to modify the parameters in GTMOAuth2SignIn.m

But it doesn't explain how to do this. I'm using cocoapods so I only have access to the headers.

Comment: Hi, any answer to this ? I'm facing the same issue.
Thanks