# Firebase Google SignIn asks every time for permissions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented a Google SignIn with Firebase in my iOS app, following the Firebase guide. The problem is that every time I test the login, it always asks for permissions.
 [image]

Here is the code of AppDelegate involved in Google SignIn:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }


        print("Logged in with Google successfull")


        // ... Firebase authentication ...

    }
}
```

And here the code of View Controller with GIDSignInButton:

```
import UIKit

class IntroViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        signInButton.style = .wide
    }


}
```

I've searched a lot on the web but found nothing... So, how can I prevent to ask for permission every time?

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: @renjithr I've edited and added some more informations

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: [GIDSignIn set approval_prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35418187/2415822)

Comment: It doesn't ask me for offline permissions

Comment: Are you signing out and signing back in at any point during your testing process? Or are you just clicking the sign-in button every time you start up your app?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I'm signing out with `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is working as intended. The issue is that you're signing out the user when you're testing your app, and the Google Sign-in library makes the assumption that if a user has explicitly signed out of your app, it should ask that user for permission again before signing that user in.

If you *don't* explicitly sign out the user, both `signIn()` calls and `signInSilently()` calls should succeed without displaying any kind of sign-in screen.

Comment: Great explanation. It helped me understand that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Do you want to check if the user is already signed in with their Google account?

```
if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()) {
    // user is signed in
} else {
    // show login
}
```

Comment: No, I would avoid asking permissions every time

Comment: @ale00 I don't understand.  You have to kick the user out to Google for sign-in/permission time they log in.  If you want to detect if they have already logged in, use the code in my answer and don't show the login-specific UI.

Comment: I know that the first time they use my app they have to accept the permissions but the problem is that every time I logout and then login with the same account they ask me for permissions (the screen at the top of the question) @JAL

Comment: @ale00 According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28764287/2415822), this is the default behavior of the new SDK.  Using an older version of the sign-in SDK you were previously able to use `GTMOAuth2SignIn` to set `approval_prompt` to `auto`, but this doesn't appear to be possible in the new version of the SDK.  The only other option I see is to use `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().trySilentAuthentication()` in the new SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the problem in this way: You have to store in your internal database your **currentID** and when you open your app you get **currentID** and consequently you get all info for your user. 
I had the same problem with the Facebook Login and I solved with this issue. 
Good job

Answer (score 1):

You can try signing in the user silently, But you will have to make sure wether or not if `GIDAuthentication` properties are already available to you or not such as - **idToken**, **accessToken**..etc

Then just call for

```
signIn.signInSilently()
```

assuming that `signIn` is the parameter of type `GIDSignIn`

look for *- (void) signInSilently* in :- [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#a61acc48595b637c8e89e7a05d21db7d2)

Answer (score 1):

On successful google sign-in, Authentication firebase user worked for me, I used following code,

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        return
    }
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken,
                                                                 accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase official documentation, you should add the following function in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

And, if you want this to work in iOS 8 and less, you should add the function you already have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication,
                                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

You can try adding both functions (As suggested by Firebsae), and see if this fixes the error. I'm not sure if this will gonna solve it, but at least is an improvement to the GID feature.

EDIT: Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin